# php artisan migrate : [PDOException] could not find driver

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-artisan, artisan-migrate

My system config is **Ubuntu 14.04 + XAMPP + Laravel 4** installed

**mysql driver is configured**  on  */opt/lampp/htdocs/larva/app/config/database.php*

```
'mysql' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'localhost',
            'database'  => 'db_larva',
            'username'  => 'root',
            'password'  => '*****',
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => 'tbl_',
        ),
```

#### PDO extension is enabled on */opt/lampp/etc/php.ini*

```
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

create table using

```
php artisan migrate:make create_users --create=users
```

which generate [2014_10_02_114459_create_users.php](http://pastebin.com/PUK3kaVj)

```
php artisan migrate:make create_orders --create=orders
```

create [2014_10_02_054103_create_orders.php](http://pastebin.com/Uw405R2B)

now on terminal what I did

```
cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/larva/ 
php artisan migrate
```

it gives error

> **[PDOException]  could not find driver**

when i run

```
php artisan migrate --database=db_larva
```

it again gives other error

> **[InvalidArgumentException]
>
>     Database [db_larva] not configured.**

Please guide me what I am doing wrong?

My guess:

- Is location correct? do run  `php artisan` inside the root folder?
- Default table structure inside `function up()` need to write some more code, may be db connection settings
- difference between `php artisan migrate:make create_users --create=users` and 
  `php artisan migrate:make create_users --create --table=users`
- I have to configure database settings somewhere else too.
- table prefix can be problematic.
- I haven't write single line to connect database, anywhere in the code yet. where to write the connection sting in code, or that is a later stage?
- `php --ini` gives different path of php ini?

  > ```
  > Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php5/cli
  > Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
  > Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php5/cli/conf.d
  > Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/05-opcache.ini,
  > /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini,
  > /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini,
  > /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini,
  > /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini,
  > /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
  > ```

Comment: check out [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36594474/laravel-locally-run-artisan-commands-effect-vm-environment)

Answer (score 6):

I got this error on xubuntu 14.04. I fixed it in 2 steps:

1. Open a terminal and run `sudo apt-get install php5-mysql`
2. change the db-host to 127.0.0.1 (instead of using localhost)

Answer (score 4):

Parameter `--database=` is used to choose DB connection. Your DB connection name is `mysql` because you have:

```
'mysql' =>
```

so you should run this query using:

```
php artisan migrate --database=mysql
```

However in `app/config/database.php` file there is a line:

```
'default' => 'mysql',
```

If you set it to `mysql` you don't need to pass `--database` parameter when migrate when you want to migrate to default database connection.

```
php artisan migrate
```

will be enough

**EDIT**

In your case you should edit your `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` file to enable PDO extension

Comment: yes. tat is the issue. `php artisan migrate` is not working, that was the original question btw

Comment: @diEcho Do you have the same error? What you have defined as default connection and which command you tried? Are you sure you don't have database set also in other environment?

Comment: @diEcho You should run in terminal `php --ini` to display ini file path and make sure in this file PDO is also enabled

Comment: I did, but surprisingly it showing different path of `ini file` but i cross checked and get that php.ini inside the `/lammp/..` file  is the working ini

Comment: @diEcho Often php cli and `standard` php have different ini file paths

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62320/discussion-between-diecho-and-marcin-nabialek).

Comment: .dll is for windows while you use Linux.
  Probably you should have extension=php_pdo_mysql.so in your /etc/php5/cli/php.ini

Comment: this worked becuase i had different php for xampp and different for command -line

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error and setup I cleared it by adding doctrine/dbal

```
composer require doctrine/dbal
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the .env file.I was also having same problem wih laravel 5.2

I have changed with the following code and it worked fine.

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=SomeRandomString

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=todo  /* Use your database Name */
DB_USERNAME=root   /* Use your host Name */
DB_PASSWORD=

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit Your .env file and update Properly.

```
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_DATABASE=YOUR DB NAME
DB_USERNAME=YOUR DB USER NAME
DB_PASSWORD= YOUR DB PASSWORD
```

use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost..

Answer (score -2):

In your `php.ini` file uncomment

```
;extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

and restart apache server.