# Laravel locally run artisan commands effect VM environment

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead, laravel-artisan, artisan-migrate

I am looking for a solution that will allow me to run `artisan` commands from my local machine and for them to take effect on my `homestead` VM.

For example, when running `php artisan migrate` the command is run using the information stored in the `.env` file points to the VM, but my terminal is trying to run them locally.

The majority of the commands run successfully because they do not need drivers from the remote machine. Running `php artisan route:list` works fine.

**How can I run `artisan` commands using a local terminal?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the following files:

**.env**

```
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_HOST_PORT=:33060
```

**homestead.yaml**

```
variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local
    - key: DB_HOST_PORT
      value: ":3306"
```

**config/database.php**

```php
'mysql' => [
    // ...
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host'   => env('DB_HOST') . env('DB_HOST_PORT'),
    // ...
]
```

Comment: It seems like this is now baked into laravel